# Booking program

Tags: javascript, node.js

what could I do to make this code more beautiful?

```
exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.aggregate(
        [{
            '$group': {
                '_id': '$booking.date',
                'name': {
                    '$first': '$booking.name'
                },
                'participants': {
                    '$sum': '$booking.participants'
                },
                'attended': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond': [{
                            '$eq': ['$attended', true]
                        }, 1, 0]
                    }
                },
                'bookings': {
                    '$sum': 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: {
                'booking.date': -1
            }
        }],
        function (error, bookings) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                res.render('admin/bookings/index', {
                    moment: moment,
                    data: bookings,
                });
            }
        }
    );
};

exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.find({
            'booking.date': req.params.id
        })
        .exec(function (error, booking) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else if (booking.length === 0) {
                res.redirect('admin/reservas');
            }
            else {
                res.render('admin/bookings/show', {
                    moment: moment,
                    data: booking,
                });
            }
        });
};


exports.changeStatus = function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.findById(req.params.id, function (error, booking) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            booking.update({
                'attended': booking['attended'] === false ? booking['attended'] = true : booking['attended'] = false
            }, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    res.end('Success!');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};


exports.destroy = function (req, res, next) {
    Booking.remove({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            res.end('Success!');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Indention in JS is usually personal preference, but given that JS has a knack for nesting a lot of stuff... I suggest 2-space indents instead.
- Try to keep lines under 80 columns whenever possible. That way, people don't run off to the right.
- Try not to use `_` and `$` in key or variable names. While they are valid, it usually doesn't make sense. Also, for valid key values, `''` is optional and since `$` and `_` are valid, then you can remove `''`.
- I saw this code:

  ```
  '$cond': [{
    '$eq': ['$attended', true]
  }, 1, 0]
  ```

  I don't know what the `1` and `0` are for. Better put them in keys instead. Also if `0` and `1` happen to be booleans, better use `true` and `false` instead to be more meaningful and we don't assume they are integers for some numeric purpose.

  ```
  cond: {
    eq: {
      attended: true
    },
    whateverOneIsFor: 1,
    whateverZeroIsFor: 0,
  }
  ```
- `if (booking.length === 0)` is the same as `if(!booking.length)` since `0` is loosely equal to `false`.
- Not entirely sure but I think you just want to toggle

  ```
  'attended': booking['attended'] === false ? booking['attended'] = true : booking['attended'] = false
  // is the same as
  'attended': booking['attended'] = !booking['attended']
  ```

Comment: impressive, if i use indention 2 the code will be more beautiful haha.. thanks for the types ;).

Answer (score 2):

"Beautiful" is a tough, highly relative term.

I can think of something that might simplify it (at least slightly): you could extract your common error handling logic into a function that takes a callback. Like so:

```
var unlessErrorOccurred = function (callback) {
    return function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error):
        } else {
            callback(data):
        }
    };
};
```

(Not tested, but hopefully you get the idea)

As an example of how it might "beautify" your code, it would transform this:

```
function (error, bookings) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        res.render('admin/bookings/index', {
            moment: moment,
            data: bookings,
        });
    }
}
```

into this:

```
unlessErrorOccured(function (bookings) {
    res.render('admin/bookings/index', {
        moment: moment,
        data: bookings,
    });
})
```

I might also suggest you extract your query (I'm assuming it's some NoSQL query) into a variable, simply because they tend to clutter up the code when inlined. In my mind at least, I should be able to think about "getting the data" without thinking about "how the data is gotten" and vice versa.